# Wrong color representation in the image

Tags: nikon, white-balance, sigma, nikon-d3300

I have an issue of getting similar color of background as the subject, 
most of the time (not all) the image comes out like this, the water in the background is certainly not the color it captured in the image, is it issue of using wrong white balance or something else? i have many images which has this issue,
can someone guide me? 
by the way, i am using Nikon D3300 & Sigma 150-600mm sports

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to correct the white balance? Are you shooting RAW?

Comment: yes i am shooting RAW, i have tried to correct white balance in post, but it does not mostly help

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10076/what-is-color-temperature-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photography

Comment: Can you post before/after white balance correction? A link to your RAW file might help too. Are you shooting with WB as "auto"?

Comment: how do i post RAW file here? is it possible in anyway? or i have to upload it somewhere and share the link here?

Comment: You can't post a RAW in here. If you can, upload it somewhere else and share the link. Anyway, it doesn't seem obvious that your camera isn't working properly. This image seems fine, even if the WB might be helped a little.

Comment: What on Earth is "the water in the background is certainly not the color it captured in the image" supposed to mean?

Comment: here is the raw file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-A2Mm_FVwWzOThRSS1PcGFBNE0

Comment: What color was the water, in your recollection?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the water had looked like with a CPL filter. My inexpert opinion is that the water colour is mainly influenced by the reflection at such a shallow angle. The duck certainly doesn't look far out from what a female duck actually looks like [again in my inexpert opinion] - by the time you tweaked the white balance to get the water blue, you'd also have a blue duck ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your RAW, **nothing seems wrong with your camera**. 
The White Balance might be a little off, but it really depends on what you want to do. Each color channel is fine and I see no trick due to bad interpolation during the RAW development.

You have been shooting at 1/30 F/9 ISO 1600. As the image is correctly exposed, you were probably shooting with **low luminosity** ([Ev100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value) about 7) so maybe 2 phenomena appeared:

- artificial light might have messed up with the color
- your eyes were adapted to this light and tricked your color perception (see [How can knowledge of human perception of color be used in photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/how-can-knowledge-of-human-perception-of-color-be-used-in-photography)).

If you want to be sure about your camera, you might want to calibrate it (see [What do I need to photograph paintings with accurate color?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72966/what-do-i-need-to-photograph-paintings-with-accurate-color) and [How do I ensure good color reproduction when photographing paintings with a mid-level DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43401/how-do-i-ensure-good-color-reproduction-when-photographing-paintings-with-a-mid) for some explanation about camera calibration).

As a side note, your image isn't very sharp. I know that the Sigma 150-600 at 600mm is sharpest about f/11 (see [photographyblog.com](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/sigma_150_600mm_f5_6_3_dg_os_hsm_sports_review/sharpness_5/)), but 1/30 seems really slow, even for a *sitting duck*. You probably have encountered motion blur and/or camera shakes. Given your low light condition, you might have gotten a better result at f/6.3... but your duck is still nice :)

Comment: Hello Olivier, thank you for your response, yes, regarding the camera settings, it was very dark and i had no option but to go down to 1/30 but camera was on ground and i know the image is not sharp (its fine) what i am really concerned about is the color of the water, if you see the color matches duck's color and the water is certainly was not reflecting that color.

Comment: I don't know what is reflected in the water, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was about the same color than the duck. We have a saying in France "La nuit, tous les chats sont gris" : by night, all cats are gray, meaning that color fidelity by night is near impossible.

Comment: "sitting duck" That is funny.